# Correct values for a Content Type's EditFormUrl property

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type, custom-form

I've developed a custom form to edit one of your Sharepoint Content Types, and am now ready to use it.

I've gone through the circuitous route of trying to use the FormsUrl markup, and have decided to take the approach of using a Feature Event Receiver to bind my custom form to my content type. This seems to work nicely.

I've just got one last snag to overcome though -- what do you use as a URL when specifying EditFormUrl?

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN Library's snippet on EditFormUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.editformurl.aspx) stipulates that one must use URL's that are relative to the root location of your content type. Personally, I've had no luck with that one.

However, the path that you specify in EditFormUrl can be relative to the root of your sharepoint instance; do be mindful of what you have put in your Schema.xml file, though.

Example:

Let's say I have a custom content type called "Lab Report". I've developed a custom form for it called EditLabReport.aspx. Rather than place this file in the _layouts folder, I've put it within my Lab Report content type "folder".

My Lab Report content type is used in a list called "Reports". In the Reports' schema.xml file,  my  section would look like this:

```
<Forms>
  [...]
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditLabReport.aspx" SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\LabReport\EditWorkOrder.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" UseLegacyForm="TRUE" />
</Forms>
```

Please note that, while the EditLabReport.aspx actually lives in the folder specified by SetupPath, it is called like this from your browser:

**/Lists/Reports/EditLabReport.aspx**

It is *this URL* that is to be specified in your EditFormUrl property.